# How to decode estimateGas Error

Tags: nodejs, ethereumjs

i'm having a problem with estimateGas function.

```
var method = contract.methods.doSomething();
var estimateGas = await method.estimateGas({
        from: address,
        to: toAddress,
    }).then(function(gasAmount){
        return gasAmount;
    })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log('estimate gas error');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
```

Sometimes i get the correct gas estimation and sometimes i get an error. But the error is not decoded:

```
{"data":"0xfdb6ca8deb677610f232d2f2fff9f4fb670c4c7e05fa20b5318b44040212e48c4793fe130000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004"}
```

How can i decode the error?

Comment: Perhaps it is one of the new custom errors from solidity https://blog.soliditylang.org/2021/04/21/custom-errors/. Can you provide the code of the function and solidity version used?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe the problem lies on the network. (Maybe it's not stable, or buggy)

so which network are you using?

does this problem still exist after switching to another EVM network (e.g. fuji, ganache, hardhat, Rinkeby... )